# Processing a couple million records per table, the query seems t be working and optimized but takes a lengthy time for execution

Tags: mysql, join

Is there any way to change or optimize this query so as to spedd up the execution time?

```
select 
    max(U.phone_mobile) as mobile_number
from 
    ccr_prod.ccr_unique_member as U 
inner join ccr_prod.ccr_member as M 
    on U.ccif = M.ccif and U.first_open_date = M.first_open_date
where M.source_id not in ('FPT', 'VLINK') 
    and U.phone_mobile not in ('', '0')
    and datediff(curdate(), U.first_open_date) > 120
group by 
    U.ccif
```

Comment: is your `u.phone_mobile` indexed?

Comment: include your db structure with existing indexes

Comment: the phone mobile is indexed along with ccif, first_open_date and source_id. And the query works fine now, returns the expected results

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only thing I can suggest (move where condition that for M table into subquery and call just needed field there):

```
select 
    max(U.phone_mobile) as mobile_number
from 
    ccr_prod.ccr_unique_member as U 
inner join ( 
    select 
      ccif, first_open_date
    FROM 
      ccr_prod.ccr_member 
    where 
      source_id not in ('FPT', 'VLINK')
) as M 
  on U.ccif = M.ccif and U.first_open_date = M.first_open_date
where  U.phone_mobile not in ('', '0')
    and datediff(curdate(), U.first_open_date) > 120
group by 
    U.ccif
```

and if it is necessary to optimize more, you can try not to find max but `LIMIT 1` if field `phone_mobile` is index that could be faster:

```
select 
    U.phone_mobile as mobile_number
from 
    ccr_prod.ccr_unique_member as U 
inner join ( 
    select 
      ccif, first_open_date
    FROM 
      ccr_prod.ccr_member 
    where 
      source_id not in ('FPT', 'VLINK')
) as M 
  on U.ccif = M.ccif and U.first_open_date = M.first_open_date
where  U.phone_mobile not in ('', '0')
    and datediff(curdate(), U.first_open_date) > 120
OREDR BY
    U.phone_mobile DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

by the way you can improve performance if replace this condition:

```
datediff(curdate(), U.first_open_date) > 120
```

with some constant prepared like:

```
U.first_open_date < '2014-12-20 00:00:00'
```

Comment: I'm missing why the first proposed optimization would be anything that the query optimizer shouldn't be expected to consider anyway.

Comment: The second proposal, though, is plain wrong.  `U.phone_mobile` is neither a grouping column nor an aggregate function of the groups.  MySQL actually allows that (though it is disallowed by SQL), but you only get one value per group, and you don't necessarily know which one that will be.  You then order the *groups* by phone number.  It's not the same thing as the original query at all.

Comment: your query will check all records after join with condition, my first query will cut some records from M table before joining so that could bring some speed

Comment: @JohnBollinger about group - yes you are right, I didn't mention because my point was not about group but about MAX function. will fix it now :-)

Comment: Only the query optimizer can say anything about which conditions are used at which point in the query plan.  MySQL is free to roll conditions from the `WHERE` clause into the join step, and to pull join conditions out for post-filtering.  There is no reason to think that your first query would perform any differently than the original.

Comment: @JohnBollinger that is why I didn't say he should, or I guarantee the performance improvements but just to try that

Comment: Your revised second query does not produce the same result as the original.  It gives the single largest phone number among those for rows that meet the filter condition, as opposed to the maximum for each `ccif`.  Moreover, there is no reason whatever to think that it would be cheaper to sort a list and choose the first element than to just choose the maximum.  One can only hope that the optimizer would be clever enough to convert the `ORDER BY` alternative back to `MAX()`, because MAX is O(n), but sorting is (at best) O(n log n).

Comment: The first solution worked well, even though i ran a limited results query before to test it. I will run a full execution uncached and observe the execution time

Comment: Not sure what do you mean about  *as opposed to the maximum for each ccif* because I beleive that `INNER JOIN` is a filter that guarrantee that result is filtered by ccif. and MAX against ORDER BY I beleive that for the indexed field ORDER BY with LIMIT 1 will bee faster then MAX

Comment: The original query returns one row *for each distinct value of `ccif`*, that row having the maximum phone number among all rows of the joined, filtered result having that `ccif`.  Yours returns a single row containing the maximum phone number over all rows of the joined, filtered result.

Comment: @JohnBollinger oh... I see I think I've got your point and you are right. I will rewrite that second query.   But I think finally OP was asking just for one row/record. Because if not he need another field in result `u.ccif` but he didn't use any. just `phone_mobile` that means that he  expects just the phone number without ccif in result. Which is weird, I am agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

There's no obvious egregious problem with the query itself.  If there are millions of records per table, then it is likely to be costly.  The only thing I suggest for the query itself is to change

```
    and datediff(curdate(), U.first_open_date) > 120
```

to

```
    and U.first_open_date < date_sub(curdate() INTERVAL 120 DAY)
```

MySQL can (should) evaluate the `date_sub()` once for all, instead of computing a `date_diff()` millions of times.

Other than that, be sure you have an indexes on `ccr_prod.ccr_unique_member.ccif` and on `ccr_prod.ccr_member.ccif`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have indices on the fields but not sure if there are any for ccif in both tables, will check. I have thought about changing that operation for checking the open date